# Why does IsNumeric() return False when given a number from a text line

Tags: python, python-3.x, isnumeric

I am working on some python code that will evaluate each line of a file, and if that line is a number, it should return false and ignore that line.  This code comes from https://github.com/geoff604/sbv2txt/blob/master/README.md and I am working to modify it.

However, no matter which line gets passed to the IsNumeric() function, it still evaluates as `False`.  I hardcoded the same number as a string `"2"` and it evaluated this correctly as `True`.

Is there something I am missing when evaluating lines of text?

```
import sys

def isCaptionText(lineIndex):
    if lineIndex.isnumeric():
        print('True')
        return False
    else:
        return lineIndex

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Arguments: [source sbv filename] [destination txt filename]')
    sys.exit()

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1:
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'a') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            if isCaptionText(line):
                f2.write(line)

print('Output complete. File written as ' + sys.argv[2])
```

The file I am analyzing is text I will list in shortened form below.

```
2
00:00:04,360 --> 00:00:08,861
St. Louis' home for arts,
education and culture.

3
00:00:08,861 --> 00:00:11,444
(upbeat music)

4
00:00:12,290 --> 00:00:13,610
- [Woman] But we're in a global pandemic.

5
00:00:13,610 --> 00:00:16,000
We're also in a global blood shortage.

6
00:00:16,000 --> 00:00:18,230
- [Man] The more I dug,
the more it took me back
```

Answer (score 2):

So, whenever you have a new line, python sees the text along with a new line. For example: if the line is `1`, the `f1.readlines()` sees that as `1\n`, hence the `isNumeric` will return false. The trick here is to use [strip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp)

```
for index, line in enumerate(Lines):
if isCaptionText(line.strip()):
   print(line)
```

Comment: @user3324136 if you think this is the right answer, can you please accept it?

Answer (score 1):

- Because everyline in file have a newline symbol which depends on the OS you use, such as the first line `2`, it is actually `2\n` in Windows.
- You can use `replace` or `strip` to get ride of newline symbol if you want to run your code on specific OS.

#### example fixed code on Windows:

```
with open("input.txt") as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        print(line.replace("\n","").isnumeric())

input.txt

2
00:00:04,360 --> 00:00:08,861
St. Louis' home for arts,
education and culture.

3
00:00:08,861 --> 00:00:11,444
(upbeat music)

4
00:00:12,290 --> 00:00:13,610
- [Woman] But we're in a global pandemic.

5
00:00:13,610 --> 00:00:16,000
We're also in a global blood shortage.

6
00:00:16,000 --> 00:00:18,230
- [Man] The more I dug,
the more it took me back
```

#### result:

```
True
False
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: Thank you for this insight.  That makes sense.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

using try and except block

```
try:
    int(lineIndex)
    print('True')
    return True
except ValueError:
    return False
```

or using `type()`

```
if type(lineIndex) == int:
    print('True')
    return False
else:
    return lineIndex
```

if you have decimals check for `float`